# Sortable Table Jquery Script works locally in Firefox but not hosted

Tags: jquery, firefox, blogger

After searching endlessly, I've been trying to implement a Sortable Table in blogger, it works  on Chrome/Safari, however it doesn't work when it's loaded on Firefox.

I've tried the Script locally on Firefox and it works.

I am using Tablesorter from: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

My page is hosted here: http://www.shellyinreallife.com/p/restaurants-nyc.html

The script is here:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://artknow.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/Site/librarys/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
     function() {
        $("#myTable").tablesorter({sortList: [[3,1], [4,0]]});
     }); 
</script>
```

I tried changing the function from `$(document).ready` to `$(document).load`, but that didn't work. Also have moved the script down to under where the table is.

Any help will be great!

Thanks!!

Comment: Firefox reports that `TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function`. It seems to be conflicting with Disqus.

Comment: It works for me on Chrome and Firefox...

Comment: Try loading disqus in the footer.

Comment: I've removed disqus from the page to try to troubleshoot this. Still not working in Firefox for me...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a bit of a stupid question, Blogger needs all javascript within a post to have no spaces or line breaks, so once I took all of those out inside my script, it started working. Just wanted to leave the answer here for anyone else who might be looking!

Answer (score 0):

This is based on what is needed for tablesorter to function:

1) the sortable headers are in a `<th>` tag inside the `<thead>` tag.

2) Make sure you are including the tablesorter `<script>` tag before you call `.tablesorter()`

These are required for the `.tablesorter()` function to work.

you can also try to change `$(document).ready(` to just `$(function() {`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried changing from $(document).ready( to just $(function() { but no luck for me, thanks!